# Python cli module import not found

Tags: python, setuptools, docopt

I am trying to run a packaged cli, which does dynamic imports. When I run the code through the main cli script it works as expected. However after I package the code up using `setup.py sdist`and then install the dist tar with pip. The cli itself gives an import error `ImportError: No module named`. All of the modules are in the same folder as the `cli.py` file.

This is how I have created my main called `cli.py`

```
def main():
    args = docopt(__doc__, version="1.0")
    argv = [args['<command>']] + args['<args>']
    module = importlib.import_module(args['<command>'])
    print(docopt(module.__doc__, argv=argv))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my setup.py looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='testing-cli',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['testing']
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': ['testing-cli = testing.cli:main'],
    }
)
```

Any ideas as to why when packaged I get an import error when it is packaged but when running like `./cli.py <arg>` it imports fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script will import modules from *its directory*, not from your current directory. That means that if you run `/some/directory/cli.py module`, it will look for `module` in `/some/directory/module.py`.

I presume that you're running `cli.py` from the directory with the other modules, but when it gets installed, `testing-cli` goes to some `/usr/local/bin` which doesn't contain the other modules. They are instead stored in a `testing` package on `sys.path`. So you actually need to do this:

```
importlib.import_module("testing." + args['<command>'])
```

or possibly through a relative import:

```
importlib.import_module("." + args['<command>'], package="testing")
```

This will mean that your script will stop working when you run it from the build directory, unless you installed the package. To fix that, use `python setup.py develop`, which will mock-install the package onto `sys.path`.
(Or more straightforward, `export PYTHONPATH=.` That will put your current directory on `sys.path` and make the `testing` subdir visible as a package)